# Did my text data come from two distinct distributions?

Tags: classification, clustering, feature-selection, cosine-similarity, tf-idf

I have labeled text data from two different classes. I have calculated tfidf feature representation of all the sentences in question. I have a huge matrix where rows are sentences and columns are tfidf scores for each word in them.  Using these features I have implemented a random forest classifier to classify the two classes and achieved reasonable accuracy. But the initial hypothesis that I started with was: Is there some n-dimensional space where my text data separate out? Or do the sentences belonging to each class cluster in some n-dimensional space? Can you suggest some way of doing that?

---

I thought of it this way:  I will take two feature vectors at random and calculate the pairwise similarity. The pairs will be from either $(+1,+1)$,$(-1,-1)$, or $(+1,-1)$. (Given I have two classes $+1$ and $-1$). Repeat this multiple times. Now I will get three distributions. From that, we will be able to say how much $+1$ is different from $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

There are techniques to find the linear projection where classes best separate. That would be worth a try, because you can actually study the projection in terms of word influence.

Look for the classic

- Fisher's Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA buy not the Dirichlet one)
- Large Margin Nearest Neighbors (LMNN)

And probably some more recent developments, too.